# Prevent Deadlock when updating rows of a single table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, deadlock

I have a table called as `Banners` which contains columns `BID`, `impressions` etc etc...

Also, I've created `StoredProcedure` which is excuted on Web Page Load.

**Stored Procedure**

```
 DECLARE @slot int               
 DECLARE @final varchar(MAX)               
 DECLARE @URL varchar(MAX)             
 DECLARE @ID varchar(MAX)                
 set @slot =0               
 SET @URL='';               
 SET @ID=0                      
 SET @final='';                  

 BEGIN               
 WHILE(@slot <= 6)               
 BEGIN               
 SET @slot= @slot+1             

IF EXISTS(select BID from Banners (NOLOCK) where Slot=@slot AND SectionID =199 AND UserType in (@IsAnonymous,2) AND Enabled=1)               
 BEGIN                  
  SET @final = (select TOP 1 '<div class=''sidebar-img''><a href ='''+ URL +''' id='''+CONVERT(varchar(10),BannerID)            
  +''' target=''_blank'' onclick=''Click(this)'';><img alt='''+Alt+''' src='''+BannerImage+''' height=''250'' width=''250''></a></div>'                  
  FROM Banners (NOLOCK) where Slot=@slot AND  Enabled=1 AND UserType in (@IsAnonymous,2)                   
  AND SectionID =199
  ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID()))            

 IF(@final<>'')               
 BEGIN               
  SET @URL  = @URL + @FINAL            
  SET @ID =(select replace( (select SUBSTRING(@final,charindex(' id=',@final)+5,4)),'''',''));                  
  UPDATE Banners set impressions +=1 where BID=CONVERT(INT,@ID); <-- **this causes DEADLOCK**                  
 END               
 ELSE               
  SET @URL  = @final              
 END                
 ELSE              
 BEGIN            
  CONTINUE            
 END                     
 END                     
  SET @BannerHTML = @URL         
 END
```

Mainly the `deadlock issue` occurred on the `update statement` , where we are updating the `Banners Table`.

Please let me know any suggestion to prevent `Deadlock`.

Comment: Well, there is only the possibility of a deadlock when two processes run in parallel on the same resource. Did you check which two processes collide? Do you know the root-cause already and now try to avoid it? If so, can you provide the query which collides? It would be helpful.

Comment: @Ionic I've already summarized in SP....

Comment: Yes but you can't get a deadlock with yourself! Locks are by design per sessions. If your procedure runs in one session, it has access to all locked resources by itself. This means you cannot have a deadlock with your own procedure. EXCEPT (which isn't included in your text) you run the same procedure in parallel (multiple times at the same time). Do you?

Comment: Deadlock happens when two processes go after the same resources, but in different orders. Process A holds resource X and goes after resource Y.  Process B holds resource Y and goes after resource X.  Both processes A and B wait forever on the other to "let go" of the resource they want.  SQL Server declares a Deadlock.  You need to do a SQL Trace/Profile with deadlock events on, and take a look at WHAT is deadlocking, an with WHO.

Comment: @Ionic yes i've tried, and on update statement it say's DEADLOCK

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way. You cannot have a deadlock with your own process. Again the same question... Do you run the query in parallel? Are there some other processes using the table, etc. etc. The same questions as in the comment before again.

Comment: @Ionic This SP is called on PageLoad....so many users when hits a page this SP is called....

Comment: Ah good finally an answer. ;-) I'll provide you two solutions at lunch time.

Answer (score 0):

I'll would prefer to avoid such a construct as you designed it.

First of all, I think that your Object `Mercola_Banners` is a view which uses your table `Banners`, right? This may cause the deadlock.

Anyway, i would avoid to update it directly if you have a table like banners, which is updated very often.

You have two options in my opinion.

1. If your application allows it, you can use `OPTIMISTIC LOCKING` which will use a bit of your tempdb to store versions of your rows. In this case, every transaction can possibly use a different version of a row. Which means, If your transaction runs, it may use version one of your row. After you update the Banners table, it create a second version. If the next page load occurs, it will use version two of the row and update it to version three. If the first transaction ends, there is no reference to version one anymore and it will be dropped. **But**, it can cause some false updates, if you run two transactions nearly at the same time, they can overlap each other. Example: Transaction 1 starts, read version 1. Transaction 2 starts, which reads version 1 too. Transaction 1 updates the row to version 2 (which updates impressions to 2). In the next step Transaction 2 generates another row as version 3 (which also updates impressions from 1 to 2). In the end, Transaction 2 and 3 ends and only version 3 will exist in the end. Which means you have 2 impressions instead the real 3 impressions. This may be an issue for you.
2. You should (which i recommend in a higher pressure area), use an insert into an staging table instead. The staging table can be interpreted every minute or every 5 minutes (e.g.) and used to update the `impressions`-column. After updating the rows, you can drop the rows from the staging table. This way you decouple the update. During the update, you may cause an exclusive lock, which prevents a read from the `banners`-table. The insert will only cause a exclusive row lock, which shouldn't hurt that much.

Comment: It should be Banners not Mercola_Banners

Comment: Check out the SP again...i've modified

Comment: Ah okay. Anyway it is the same answer for me. I just mentioned the view as I think that it points to the Banner too. This means the possibility that I'm right is just even higher than before your update.